# FXCop is catching Application_Start() event because it's not static

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fxcop

I just hooked up the Static Code Analysis functionality in my Visual Studio 2010 MVC3 project, and it's throwing CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic on my Application_Start() event. I don't necessarily want to globally suppress this message, but I really dislike the thought of littering my code with the suppress attribute.

Are there any other options? What's everybody else doing for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...I really dislike the thought of littering my code with the suppress attribute.

Doesn't the Code Analysis feature give you the option of placing the suppresions in a separate global suppressions file instead of inline?

Failing that, you could always stop using the Code Analysis feature and switch to using the FxCop GUI, which allows you to suppress individual messages, with an optional comment.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I thought putting it in the project suppression file would make it globally ignore that check. I just verified that the project suppression file does in fact scope it to the method level.